# What is the equation for this numeric input/output pattern?

Tags: math

I am trying to come up with a single variable function that can reproduce the expected output value for a given input value.  The following table illustrates a pattern with numeric input ranges that produce an expected output number.

```
   0 ...    74 =    1
  75 ...   749 =   10
 750 ...  7499 =  100
7500 ... 74999 = 1000
```

At least, I expect an equation can handle it.  Otherwise, can you provide some pseudo code that can accomplish this pattern?

Comment: Since we are all programmers, could you specify whether the input is float/double, integer/long?And same for output.

Comment: To give more of an impression that you are aware of being in a community which exclusively discusses programming problems, please specific and tag the programming language of your choice.

Comment: @Yunnosch There are no arbitrary constraints on the numeric values.  (well, we can probably ignore negative values)  I am aware that this is a programmer community and my question is born from programming work.  But my question isn't language-specific.  If there is a better place for asking math questions, I'll be happy to go elsewhere.

Comment: The question is for a programmers perspective language specific. Most languages have an integer division, which would on the one hand make rounding irrelevant but would on the other hand make the use of the usual `pow()` function questionable. So, if you do not specify a language at least specify input/output formats. If you insist on not doing that and that the question is pure math, then the math gurus will probably have some issues with how to express rounding, which programmers in their world of anyway "arbitrarily restricted numbers" are happy to ignore.

Comment: And, as you can see in the answer  (by I believe a programmer), programmers do not have a problem with mapping 0 to 0, they introduce a special case. For a math representation of the formula that gets messy. So, an answer which manages to answer purely in math will probably not be what you want. And an answer which is practically applicable (like below) is, strictly speaking, not an answer to your "pure math" question.

Comment: @Yunnosch The languages I work in are not strongly typed.  Any integer or float value may be provided as input.

Comment: @Yunnosch My question also stated that pseudo code is acceptable, so I apologize for any impression that it was "pure math".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inputs from 8 and up:

**Divide by 74.999999, take the decimal logarithm, round up, then take the decimal exponential.**

As a formula: `output = 10^(ceil(log10(input / 74.999999)))`

This formula is only true for input `>= 8`. If the input is 0, the logarithm would give either -infinity or a math domain error. For inputs in the range `[1,7]`, you will get output 0.1 instead of 1. If you are writing code, this is easily fixed by adding an `if` statement:

```
if (input < 8)
    return 1;
else
    return 10^(ceil(log10(input / 74.999999)));
```

**Please note the `^` in this pseudocode is exponentiation, not bitwise xor**; in most languages it might be noted `10**x` or `pow(10,x)` instead of `10^x`. Thanks [@Yunnosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7733418/yunnosch) for highlighting this.

Comment: I am not sure which language that is supposed to be. But in most languages I am aware of (e.g. C, C++, Perl, Python) `^` is not doing what it should for making sense in this context.

Comment: Well, of course OP is asking for pseudo code, but this is a nasty trap to get caught in.

Comment: I'm still studying this, but I have no problems with the presentation of the answer so far.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch! I added a note right below the pseudocode to account for your comment.

Comment: @Stef Your formula seems to produce 0.1 for 1-7.  Is your solution just to throw a "max(1, <formulaResult>)" around it?  Or do you think this is a larger problem?  I'm still testing it.

Comment: Oops, you are right. Yes, you should make a particular case for 0-7. Also, note that if you want to go to higher values, you might need to add more 9 to 74.999999; but if you add too many, you might get a rounding error where 75 returns 1 instead of 10, 750 returns 10 instead of 100, etc.

Comment: @Stef Understood.  Use of "max" solves the zero problem (at least, it does in JavaScript.  Still need to test it in PHP) and conveniently solves the 1-7 as well.  So I find it acceptable.  Thanks!  I clearly need to get more comfortable with logarithms.  I never did get around to making sense of them.  So, unless somebody comes along with a more "elegant" solution, I'll accept this one tomorrow.

Comment: @pongstylin: logarithm in base 10 can be understood as returning the number of digits of its input. The log10 of a power of 10 is always an integer; log(0.01 = -2; log(0.1) = -1, log(1) = 0; log(10) = 1; log(100) = 2; log(1000) = 3; etc. Logarithm is strictly increasing, so if a number is between 100 and 1000, its logarithm will be between 2 and 3. Combining log with an appropriate rounding function fives exactly the number of digits of an integer. Logarithms in other bases give the number of "digits" in other bases; for instance, logarithm in base 2 is the number of bits.

Comment: @pongstylin Other properties of logarithms: logarithms in different bases are proportional; for any positive x, `log10(x) = log2(x) / log2(10)`. More generally, for any positive x and any positive b and c distinct from 1, `log_b(x) = log_x(x) / log_c(b)`.

Comment: @pongstylin: finally, a super cool property of logarithm is that it transforms multiplication into addition! for any positive x and y, `log(x*y) = log(x) + log(y)`. You can see this easily by thinking about "the number of digits": the number of digits of x*y is approximately the number of digits of x plus the number of digits of y. This awesome property is the historic reason why logarithms were discovered / made popular in the first place. They made precise calculations in the context of ship navigation much faster (to perform by hand before the era of computers).

Comment: @Stef I appreciate the explanation from a true enthusiast.  I had done some definition-diving of my own and totally see why you are using log10 to get a roundable result then using pow10 to bring it back up to size.  It is an interesting custom rounding solution.  Usually, custom rounding solutions might first divide the value by a factor of 10, round, then multiply the value by the same factor of 10.  But this log10 trick allows us to round up to the NEXT order of magnitude as opposed to rounding up to a FIXED order of magnitude.  Fancy.